# Office 365 Support for Custom Application page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365

We are using SharePoint 2013 and planning to customize the document upload window as shown in the picture. [image]

This is a customized application page. Could anyone advice me whether this kind of customization is supported in office 365  if we move the solution to cloud based office 365 Enterprise version?

Comment: No i think  you cannot create new or modify existing  layouts page in o365.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot customize upload.aspx in Sharepoint Online directly.

There are couple of workarounds for doing so:

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/64202.aspx

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/172776.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No, you won't be able to move that to Office 365.  You'll need to recreate the design entirely in JavaScript. You can deploy a [custom action](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/Adding-jQuery-to-Every-Page-in-a-SharePoint) in a sandbox solution that will allow you to hook up a JS reference, and then render your markup there.

Now, I assume you actually want to *do* something with those checkboxes. That's a different story, and the more difficult one if you ask me.